# Ubuntu Openstack: Does the default Landscape Installer provide High Availibilty

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am looking at deploying Ubuntu Openstack in a production environment via the Landscape Autopilot. I am unable to locate documentation detailing its default configuration which would assist me in answering questions like "is HA built in".

Can anyone point me towards reliable sources of information?

Comment: You may find this documentation useful: http://docs.openstack.org/high-availability-guide/content/

Answer (score 1):

The currently released version does not support HA. That's coming shortly in an upcoming release.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.openstack.org/high-availability-guide/content/

Comment: @ElderGeek The question is about the Landscape Autopilot reference architecture, not upstream OpenStack's.

Comment: @0xF2 Please provide DDB with better, more useful information if you can. I'm sure it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Landscape Autopilot will install Ubuntu OpenStack, as defined in the Ubuntu OpenStack reference architecture. This is also in the process of a major update, so I can't point you to a source of relevant documentation, but I can promise that both that and documentation for the Autopilot installer are in progress, and I will add links to this answer when they are finished.